# Get Edited TD values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table whose span is populed by PHP  variables. The table is showing up pretty well, showing the data present in the database. The following is the table row, which is wrapped inside a PHP while loop.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer" id="sample_editable_1" role="grid" aria-describedby="sample_editable_1_info">
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td contenteditable="false" class="sorting_1">
      <span class="sl"> </span>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="false">
      <span class="itid"><?php echo $itid1; ?></span>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="false">
      <span class="name"><?php echo $name1; ?></span>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="false">
      <span class="price"> <?php echo $price1; ?></span>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="false">
      <span class="qty"><?php echo $qty1; ?></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="pr_edit" value="edit" href="javascript:;"> Edit </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="pr_elete" href="javascript:;"> Delete </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The following is jQuery function I am using to pull the Data.

```
$('#sample_editable_1').on('click', '.pr_edit', function() {
  console.log("here");
  var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
  $.each(currentTD, function() {
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
  });

  var ino = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.itid").text();
  var iname = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.name").text();
  var iprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.price").text();
  var iqty = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.qty").text();
});
```

However, I am not able to retrieve the values from the fields that are edited. The rest of the TR cells are Okay. How do I retrieve modified values from the Table cells I have edited?

## IMPORTANT NOTE:

I am able to obtain values that are from unedited TR cells. The jQuery selectors are correct.

Comment: You're missing lots of closing `>`s in your html.

Comment: There is no matching element for the selector `#sample_editable_1`

Comment: None that I can see.

Comment: That's a problem then.  If the jQuery selector doesn't match any DOM elements, your click event wont be bound to anything and the jQuery you've posted will never run.  Your selector needs to be able to find a matching DOM element.

Comment: I have updated the question. Selector works well. For the record, I am able to obtain the cell values in jQuery if no edits are made on the cell. However, whenever edits are made, that particular cell values updates to blank. That means the selectors are working fine and the field is being reset, but no value.

Comment: **Editing <td> you clear inner <span>**. and your selectors won't match anything. You have to make <span> editable, not its container <td>. BTW you can read those values after editing finished (then I suppose your 2nd code snippet is executed/placed elsewhere).

Comment: How to make span editable? Converting it into textbox?

Comment: @AkhilKPAULOSE the code, as you have it now, is retrieving edited values.  You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/8ugf2vao/1/  Check the console log every time you click edit.

Comment: Where is your TD editing code ? To which you want to get ?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `contenteditable` to true, you can store the current value in with the jQuery [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function.

For example:

```
$(this).data('original-value', $(this).text());
```

Then, when it's time to read all of the values in the table, you can compare the current value of the `td` content to the original value. The implementation would be something like this:

```
$('#sample_editable_1 td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('original-value') !== $(this).text()) {
    alert('this cell has been edited');
    alert('original value was: ' + $(this).data('original-value'));
    alert('new value is: ' + $(this).text());
  }
});
```